# SHC converted shell 'Breaks' on system reboot

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, encryption

I am making a public image on AWS and so am required to 'hide' some shell scripts, but still have them freely usable. We're not looking for the utmost security, I understand SHC can be reverted if a user actually wishes to do so, but it's enough for my requirement.

So that's all good! I have a shell, 'test.sh'. I convert it, 'shc -f test.sh'. The output is a .x and a .x.c file. I run './test.sh.x' - It runs exactly as I expect it to.

So far so good...

But if at any point I reboot the instance, then when I try and run './test.sh.x' again it fails and just outputs a load of random binary stuff.

I have absolutely zero idea what is causing this or why it is causing this. The file is not being edited, or moved, or anything.. It just suddenly does not work anymore. Why?? I've searched online but can't seem to find anyone having this same issue, so any help will be massively appreciated.

And to note, a valid alternative that may not result in the same issue (worth testing at least) is most welcome, as I'm not dead-set on using SHC specifically, it's just the only one I know about currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oooookay, well I unfortunately was never able to fix this issue. Even if I install SHC after I create an instance from my own AMI, and then compile the scripts at this point, the scripts only work until I reboot the system and then they no longer work.

So instead I found a different solution using Bash-Obfuscator, installed and run as follows:

```
dnf -y install npm nodejs
npm install -g bash-obfuscate

bash-obfuscate test_input.sh -o test_output.sh
```

And that perfectly does what I needed. There was, however, one thing I quickly learned using Bash-Obfuscator which was quite important - Do NOT have 'echo' commands across multiple lines as it will break your script. The following will break when obfuscated using this command:

```
echo "Hello
World"
```

But replacing that with this (which is practically the same thing) works perfectly okay (must be some way the parser is coded):

```
TEST_VAR="Hello
World"

echo "${TEST_VAR}"
```

Hope this helps anyone in future.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same probem. Found a workaround.

**Problem:** Compiled simple shell script to executable with command line:
`shc -S -f <my-script-filename>`

Tested resulting executable several times. Runs as expected.

Rebooted machine.

Tried to run executable.
Executable fails and outputs random-seeming characters to stdout

**Workaround**: Recompiled with modified flags:
`shc -r -S -f <my-script-filename>`

Executable now survives reboot. Works as required.